# Pandas loc gives different values for same filters

Tags: python, pandas

The number of rows in my data frame for similar filters is different and I cannot figure why. Here is my code -

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Automobile_price_data_clean-f18.csv")
df
df.loc[(df['body-style']== 'hatchback') & df['city-mpg']]
a = df.loc[(df['body-style']== 'hatchback') & df['city-mpg']]
foo_1 = a.count()
b = df.loc[(df['body-style']== 'hatchback')]
foo_2 = b.count()
foo_1 == foo_2
```

Here is my data - https://paste.pythondiscord.com/apizixigay.apache

Answer (score 0):

Surely the queries are not the same.

```
  a = df.loc[(df['body-style']== 'hatchback') & df['city-mpg']]# incorporates city-mpg and hence restrictive. To check further try;
```

`a.shape` versus `b.shape`

and

`a['city-mpg'].nunique()` versus `b['city-mpg'].nunique()`